# Why there are two calls for post?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

The below code is used in reactjs project, the used redux and redux-saga also.

```
app.post('/api/getAllMusic', async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const config = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${req.body.token}`
            }
        };

        const allMusic = await axios.post(GET_ALL_MUSIC, {}, config)
        return res.send(allMusic.data)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return res.status(500).json({ message: error.response.data.message });
    }
});
```

Why there are two calls for post??

Comment: Does the call has options in one of the method and other one as POST

Comment: No all are POST

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of tbe call from network

Comment: This looks more like Express. Please describe the exact issue you think you’re having.

Comment: I really think you should ask the person who designed this API. It's really impossible to answer your question as we cant see the bigger picture.